# Under what circumstances can a PHP file's source code become viewable in a browser?

Tags: php, linux, apache

I'm fairly new to server administration and PHP programming and I've read a few times that under certain circumstances it's possible that a PHP file's source code might be shown in the browser. This is concerning to me, as it would be very bad if that happened on a business website.

1. Under what circumstances might this happen?
2. Would putting PHP files above the public_html folder prevent the file from *ever* being viewed in a browser, eliminating this risk (however it occurs)?

Comment: If the server isn't configured to parse .php files

Comment: If you use files .inc. Normally, the servers like APACHE, yet configured to parse .php files

Comment: if you have the .phps file extension configured/allowed

Comment: If the php code isn't within `<?php`

Comment: If you run PHP as a plain CGI or via mod_cgid. Read more here:http://www.php-security.net/archives/9-New-PHP-CGI-exploit-CVE-2012-1823.html

Comment: Aside from what's been told above: if you have `highlight_file(__FILE__);` in your code.

Comment: You might have been using PHP short tags (i.e. `<?` and `?>`) and accidentally set the directive `short_open_tag` to false.

Answer (score 3):

> 1 . Under what circumstances might this happen?

**A**:   If the server isn't configured to parse .php files (Thanks @MarkBaker for the brevity)

> 2 . Would putting PHP files above the public_html folder prevent the file from ever being viewed in a browser, eliminating this risk (however it occurs)?

**A**:   No, if your server is configured to use aliases or follow symlinks the files might get accessible again from remote

---

The only solution is to configure your server in a way that it handles PHP properly - or denies serving files with that extension at all.